# Re-run Reactive from Shinyalert Callback

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

Is there a way to re-run a reactive via the `callbackR` argument in the `shinyalert` function?

I'm making a CRUD shiny app which includes a reactive that fetches data from a database. The data in this reactive is then used in a `renderDT` function to display a datatable.

Once a user clicks a button, `shinyalert` issues a callback that writes additional data to the database and alerts users that the data was written. I'd like the callback to also re-run the reactive to refresh the data from the database and display the new values in the database.

Is there a way to do this through `callbackR`? I'm also open to other approaches to this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around where I include `shinyjs::click("fetchData")` in the `callbackR` argument and create the reactive as follows:

```
data <- reactive({
          input$fetchData
          ...})
```